# HttpURLConnection cannot establish connection for HTTP GET, returns Exception: null

Tags: java, android, http

I am trying to send a simple GTTP GET command to google using HttpURLConnection but it throws a 'null' exception at urlConnection.connect(); I have both INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission in my manifest. Any ideas why I can't establish the connection?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textView;
private URL url;
byte[] answer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textID);
    Log.i("Trace", "A");

    try{
        url = new URL("http", "www.google.com", 80, "index.html");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        Log.i("Trace", "B");

        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        Log.i("Trace", "C");
        //urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

        urlConnection.connect();  //BREAKS HERE
        Log.i("Trace", "D");

        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        Log.i("Trace", "E");
        byte[] b = new byte[10];
        in.read(b);
        textView.setText(b.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("Trace", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Put the HTTP call in Asynctask and call it as a background task. It should work.

Comment: Tip: [Use Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html)

Comment: And I don't think it is a 'null' expecption. It should be a NetworkOnMainThread exception.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the HTTP call in Asynctask worked.